# Where can I request discovery on election software?

Tags: discussion

Moved addendum inquiring about voting software out of question to stay on topic.
What is an appropriate location?

**[Ignore]: Storing the text here until I can dump it in a legal location.**

*Which platform offers full support for the NOTA option in RCV?*

Where can polling data be processed such that:

- Complicated methods (such Meeks STV) are available for use
- Ballots including some or all unranked candidates are considered
- Static win thresholds which account for unranked candidates are considered
- Redistribution between rounds is displayed
- Rounds continue until ALL candidates meet the static win threshold

all as defined in [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/57652/ranked-choice-voting-which-platforms-allow-for-and-display-nota-eliminations).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently here:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/